# apply ng-style for ng-repeat results based on another array of object data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-style

I am trying to display the JSON data I have in the following format. I was stuck at one point where the data that is being displayed in tiles is coming from on service. And it needs to be styled based on the data coming from another service.

I'm unable to find a middleground where I can achieve this functionality. Can anyone take a look at my code and help me?

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var cpiApp = angular.module('cpiApp', []);

    cpiApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, $rootScope, CPIndexAPIService) {
      var configArray = CPIndexAPIService.getConfig();
      configArray.then(function successCallback(res) {
        $scope.configData = res.data;
        console.log($scope.configData);
      },
      function errorCallback(data, status, headers) {
        console.log('Unable to fetch Configuration');
      });

      var titleArray = CPIndexAPIService.getTitle();
      titleArray.then(function successCallback(res) {
        $scope.titleData = res.data;
        console.log($scope.titleData);
      },
      function errorCallback(data, status, headers) {
        console.log('Unable to fetch Title');
      });

      var areasArray = CPIndexAPIService.getAreas();
      areasArray.then(function successCallback(res) {
        $scope.areasData = res.data;
        console.log($scope.areasData);
      },
      function errorCallback(data, status, headers) {
        console.log('Unable to fetch Title');
      });

      var cfDataArray = CPIndexAPIService.getProjectData('CF');
      cfDataArray.then(function successCallback(res) {
        $scope.cfDataArray = res.data;
        console.log($scope.cfDataArray);
        var cc = document.getElementByClassName("data-tile-small");
        console.log(cc);
      },
      function errorCallback(data, status, headers) {
        console.log('Unable to fetch data');
      });
    });

    cpiApp.factory('CPIndexAPIService', function($http) {
        return {
          getConfig: function() {
            return $http.get('JSON/GetConfig.json');
          },
          getTitle: function() {
            return $http.get('JSON/GetTitle.json');
          },
          getAreas: function() {
            return $http.get('JSON/GetProjects.json');
          },
          getProjectData: function(id) {
            return $http.get('JSON/bodyData/'+id+'/'+id+'.json');
          }
        };
    });

})();
```

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.navbar {
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #424242;
}
.logo, .logo-title {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo {
    width: 6%;
}
.logo>img {
  width: 100%;
}
.logo-title {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.area-title {
  margin-right: 60px;
  font-size: 26px;
}
.logo-title, .area-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.area-title {
  float: right !important;
}
.text-wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-wrapper {
  float: right;
  width: 38%;
  height: 435px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.data-tile-small {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-width: 120px;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: calc((100% - 60px)/3);
  height: calc((100% - 10px)/2);
  background: #424242;
  padding: 5px;
}
.data-tile-large{
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #424242;
  padding: 5px;
}
.project-tile-title {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.project-cpivalue{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200%;
  font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cpiApp">
  <head>
    <title>CF Compliance Index</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Consumer Facing Compliance Index Dashboard">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="images/adidas_logo_vector_inverted_resized.png" alt={{configData.logo.alternateText}}>
        </div>
        <div class="logo-title">
          {{titleData.title}}
        </div>
        <div class="area-title">
          <input type="hidden" name="" value={{areasData.projects[0].Key}}>
          {{areasData.projects[0].Value}}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 80px;padding: 10px;">
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <div class="data-tile-small" ng-repeat="project in cfDataArray.projects">
          <input type="hidden" name="project-id" value={{project.key}}>
          <div class="project-tile-title">
            {{project.value}}
          </div>
          <div class="project-cpivalue" ng-attr-id={{'cpindex-'+$index}}>
            {{project.cpindex}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="data-tile-large" style="padding-top: 140px;padding-bottom: 150px;">
          <input type="hidden" name="project-id" value={{cfDataArray.key}}>
          <div class="project-tile-title" style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">
            {{cfDataArray.value}}
          </div>
          <div class="project-cpivalue" style="line-height: 125%;">
            {{cfDataArray.cpindex}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried several ways. Nothings pans out as expected. I need to apply the style to the data present inside `.project-cpivalue` based on the JSON data coming from `configArray.thresholds`.

GetConfig.json:

```
{
    "logo" : {
        "src" : "http://chnmct247802d/cpi/images/adidas_logo_vector_inverted_resized.png",
        "alternateText" : "Adidas Logo"
    },
    "pageTitle" : "Compliance Index Dashboard",
    "thresholds" : [{
            "Value" : 85,
            "color" : "crimson"
        },{
            "Value" : 94,
            "color" : "coral"
        },{
            "Value" : 104,
            "color" : "yellow"
        },{
            "Value" : 109,
            "color" : "darkseagreen"
        },{
            "Value" : 110,
            "color" : "green"
        }
    ],
    "marquee" : {
        "needed" : false,
        "content" : "Some Text Here ..."
    },
    "refresh" : {
        "needed" : false,
        "pageRefreshInterval" : 60000
    }
}
```

Please have a look at this and suggest me a way forward.

Comment: Are your style array and your object array parallel arrays?  (Does style[n] match object[n]?)

Comment: No. I don't have any array that contains styles. I need to apply the colors available in thresholds[n].color array in GetConfig.json if the value in .project-cpivalue exceeds the thresholds[n].Value